# Best Practice Regarding Types When Programming Windows?

Tags: c, winapi

I'm currently learning Windows programming through the Win32 API using Petzold's book as a resource and I was wondering if I should use the types defined in the API instead of the standard C types (ie. char instead of CHAR, DWORD instead of unsigned long). I understand that this was mostly for backwards compatibility but is there any benefit of using them right now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the Windows types only in code that's directly interfacing with Windows API, and even then, only when it matters what type you're using - like if you need to pass a pointer to that type to an API function, or for semi-opaque types like handles. Don't start writing your for loops with `INT` or `DWORD` as the loop counter variable...

Of course I may be biased... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Use the Windows types, especially for return values. You're much more likely to write portable code (i.e. works in 32-bit and 64-bit versions) that way.

Answer (score 1):

[When in rome...](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/when_in_Rome,_do_as_the_Romans_do) so yes. It makes your code "fit" in a *particular* environment.

Obviously this is more relevant if doing MFC/COM+ than, say, a (portable) console app that only makes a few WinAPI calls. (The WinAPI calls should still use the "windows types", IMOHO. They are already including anyway.)

Happy coding.